# OpenGL ES black screen

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I am a beginner to drawing with OpenGL ES and I have a problem. I am drawing a figure consisting of triangles in orthographic projection, but when I run my app, I see a black screen and system buttons only (I am using a real device and not an emulator).

Why do I get a black screen, and how could I fix it?

I am using OpenGL ES 1.0 version.

Initialization before drawing:

```
float[] verticesArray = new float[] {
        180.0f, 80.0f, 10.0f,
        260.0f, 80.0f, 10.0f,
        318.0f, 138.0f, 10.0f,

        260.0f, 80.0f, 10.0f,
        318.0f, 138.0f, 10.0f,
        318.0f, 216.0f, 10.0f,

        318.0f, 138.0f, 10.0f,
        318.0f, 216.0f, 10.0f,
        260.0f, 264.0f, 10.0f,

        318.0f, 216.0f, 10.0f,
        260.0f, 264.0f, 10.0f,
        180.0f, 264.0f, 10.0f,

        260.0f, 264.0f, 10.0f,
        180.0f, 264.0f, 10.0f,
        122.0f, 216.0f, 10.0f,

        180.0f, 264.0f, 10.0f,
        122.0f, 216.0f, 10.0f,
        122.0f, 138.0f, 10.0f,

        122.0f, 216.0f, 10.0f,
        122.0f, 138.0f, 10.0f,
        180.0f, 80.0f, 10.0f,

        122.0f, 138.0f, 10.0f,
        180.0f, 80.0f, 10.0f,
        260.0f, 80.0f, 10.0f
};
verticesAmountTotal = verticesArray.length/3;
coordsOfVerticesAmountTotal = verticesArray.length;

ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(coordsOfVerticesAmountTotal * 4);
byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
vertices = byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();       
vertices.put(verticesArray);
vertices.flip();
```

Drawing method:

```
gl.glViewport(0, 0, glGraphics.getWidth(), glGraphics.getHeight());
gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
gl.glLoadIdentity();
gl.glOrthof(0, 480, 0, 320, 30, -1);
gl.glColor4f((float)Math.random(), (float)Math.random(), (float)Math.random(), opacity);
gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, verticesAmountTotal);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code, but here are some possible things you can look at:

1. Is your call to `glViewport()` getting the values you think it is?
2. What is your clear color set to? If you set it to something like yellow, do you see anything else?
3. What is `opacity` set to?
4. Does Math.random() default to 0 if you don't seed it? If so, are you seeding it?
5. Is the vertex array getting set up before drawing?

Have you tried adding any calls to `glGetError()` to see if anything is going wrong? That might give you a clue as to what's happening.

Comment: 1) Gonna check it. 2)Clear color is not set at all, but when i drew one triangle is was not a problem, there was a red triangle on a black screen. 3)opacity is 0.1 and it is incremented by 0.1 when i touch the screen(1 max value). 4) Don't know what is seeding, is the mistake here? 5) yes, and u can see the init code above))

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear on point 5. I see you've written the init code, but are you sure it's actually getting called before you call the render code? I've made mistakes like that before, so just thought I'd mention it.

Comment: yes, im sure bcoz I drew one triangle before the same way and it was actually drawn. I will check glViewport values today, maybe the problem is hidden there as.

Comment: I ve checked glViewPort values, they are correct (

Comment: Hi again. I have changed my z values if vertices to 0 and everything started to work. I dont know why, maybe you can tell me? This is strange.

Comment: It might be because of where your virtual camera is. I see you're setting the projection matrix, but you don't show how you're setting the view matrix. If the view matrix is moved back in Z, then objects with a depth of 10 might be beyond the far plane. Or if the camera is moved forward in Z, objects might be behind the camera.